# How to import JSON File into SQLAlchemy Table using Python 3.6?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Trying to import data from a JSON File into a column `data` in a Table using SQLAlchemy.

Version looks kind of like this:

```
class  JsonTable(declarative_base()):
__tablename__ = "json_table"

id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
data = Column(JSON)


json_data = open('U:\\data.json')
data = json.load(json_data)    
for key, value in data.items():
    JsonTable
```

How to get the single JSON elements into my `data` column? JSON file looks very basic, like this

```
{
  "company": "test",
  "number": "123"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [mapping](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/orm/mapping_styles.html#classical-mappings) interface offered by SQLAlchemy:

```
metadata = MetaData()

columns = (
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('data', JSON, nullable=False),
    ...
)

jsonTable = Table('JsonTable', metadata, *columns)

class JsonTable(object):
    def __init__(self, json_data):    
      json_data = open('U:\\data.json')
      data = json.load(json_data)    
      for key, value in data.iteritems():
        setattr(self, key, value)

mapper(JsonTable, jsonTable)
```